# Extract user names from tweets without @ or RT prefix

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract user names from a Tweet without the `@` symbol or the `RT`  prefix.

Currently I'm using the `Code 1` for this purpose, which does not meet this criterion, so I have to resort to another `lambda` that cleans the undesired symbols.

**Code 1:**

```
import pandas as pd
import re
tw = 'RT @uname1, RT @uname2 @uname3, text1, text2, @uname4, text3, @uname5, RT @uname6. '

retweet_pattern = re.compile(r'(RT\s@[^\,^\s^.]+)')
mention_pattern = re.compile(r'([^RT]\s@[^\,^\s^\.]+)')

rt_unames, mt_unames = re.findall(retweet_pattern, tw), re.findall(mention_pattern, tw)
rt_unames, mt_unames
```

**Output of Code 1:**

```
(['RT @uname1', 'RT @uname2', 'RT @uname6'],
 ['2 @uname3', ', @uname4', ', @uname5'])
```

Then I have to clean the outputs with the second `lambda`, as in `Code 2`:

**Code 2**

```
rt_unames, mt_unames = list(map(lambda x: x[4:], rt_unames)), list(map(lambda x: x[3:], mt_unames))
rt_unames, mt_unames
```

**Output of Code 2**

```
(['uname1', 'uname2', 'uname6'], ['uname3', 'uname4', 'uname5'])
```

Is there a way to fix my `re` pattern so that the `RT` , the `2 @` and  `@` won't appear in the output, and I'd get rid of the second `lambda` application?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use capture groups or named capture groups

```py
pattern = r"RT\s+@*(?P<name>[^\s\,\.]+)"
text = 'RT @uname1, RT @uname2 @uname3, text1, text2, @uname4, text3, @uname5, RT @uname6. '
```

*option1*

```py
output1 = [x.group('name') for x in re.finditer(pattern, text)]
```

*option2*

```py
output2 = re.findall(pattern, text)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Could you please explain the pattern and how does it achieve the desired outcome? I guess it's the `?P<name>` part that does the job.

Comment: `(?P<name>[^\s\,\.]+)` is the capture group. `?P<name>` is optional it will help you access the group by name.

Comment: The capture group (enclosed in parentheses) captures the text matched by the regex inside them into a numbered group